# How to get json data in below format

Tags: php, mysql, json

JSON Data :

```
{"FORM_ID":51393,
"ORG_ID":1527,
"REQUEST_ACTION":"ADD",
"ADD_DATA":
{
    "RECORDS":
    [
        {
        "ID":"0",
        "COLUMNS":
        [
            {"NAME":"App Status", "VALUE":"Pending"},
            {"NAME":"Remarks","VALUE":"Application in Pending"},
            {"NAME":"App Date (dd/MMM/yyyy)" ,"VALUE":"2017-29-03 00:00:00.0"},
            {"NAME":"Applicant First Name", "VALUE":"TEST WEBSERVICES First"},
            {"NAME":"Applicant Middle Name", "VALUE":"TEST WEBSERVICES Second"},
            {"NAME":"Applicant Last Name", "VALUE":"TEST WEBSERVICES Last"},
            {"NAME":"Enquiry Center - Walk", "VALUE":"Telephonic"},
            {"NAME":"Admission City Office", "VALUE":"TestCity"},
            {"NAME":"Applicant Email Id", "VALUE":"test@test.com"},
            {"NAME":"Nationality", "VALUE":"testNationality"},
            {"NAME":"Country", "VALUE":"INDIA"},
            {"NAME":"State", "VALUE":"MAHARASTRA"},
            {"NAME":"City", "VALUE":"Mumbai"},
            {"NAME":"Permanent Country", "VALUE":"INDIA"},
            {"NAME":"Application Seq No", "VALUE":""}
            {"NAME":"Application Seq No", "Mobile No":"9999999999"}
        ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you try to do ,but if u have array

```
 echo json_encode($array);
```

if u try to get it from url

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

echo json_encode(curl_download("http://url.com")) ;
```